# Nginx rewrite rule: check for nonexistant files and folders

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, rule

I'm trying to set-up nginx rewrite rules as the following:

Original structure:

domain.com/index.php?site=project

Now I tried to mask it using the nginx rewrite engine:

```
if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
      }
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?site=$1 last;
        break;
      }
```

How do I forbid folders (stuff ending with a slash) and non-existent files?
I read a lot about

> try_files

but I can't get it to work.

at the moment I have

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
```

and

```
location @app {
rewrite ^/ /404.php last;
}
```

but it won't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Also:
Do I need to alter my PHP code?
Or is pure rewrite fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off [autoindex](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpAutoindexModule) to prevent users from looking in folders. I do't know what you mean with 'forbid non-existent files'. The visitor just gets a 404.